# "Leap of Faith" trap from Indiana Jones & The Last Crusade

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade

Indiana enters the area and doesn't see a pathway. He takes a step (or a leap of faith) and lands on the "invisible" bridge and we, as viewers, can now see the stone bridge. He throws sand on it to make the pathway visible.

Is the bridge meant to actually be invisible from every angle (aside from the sand on it now) or is it supposed to be a sort of forced perspective illusion where it's camouflaged against the pattern of rocks in the chasm?

Comment: I think the Leap of Faith might be described as a "Suspension of Disbelief" trap.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is intended to be a forced perspective illusion, as you suggest.

The knight was kept quite busy dusting it.

Comment: Not only dusting it, but he had to repaint it from time to time, to -- and hope the paint dried before dust settled on it or someone came along to find the grail.

Comment: Still, it's a pretty convincing illusion, as long as you have only one eye and stand really still in the right spot.

Comment: the fact that the access to the bridge was a very small door helped forcing the pespective illusion.